# How to Async combine multiple JSON arrays into 1 with Node.js javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, multidimensional-array

I'm using NodeJS and Async to perform multiple select queries. Therefore I want to populate the `collection` array with `firstqueryarray` and `secondqueryarray`.

How can I combine the first and second response into one array?

```
exports.relations = function (req, res) {

    var collection = [];

    async.parallel([
        function () {
            var firstqueryarray= [];
            connection.query(query1, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                for (var i in rows) {
                    firstqueryarray.push({
                        name: rows[i].name,
                        email: rows[i].email
                    });
                }
                res.json({
                    firstqueryarray: firstqueryarray
                });
            });

        }

    , function () {
            var secondqueryarray= [];
            connection.query(query2, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

                for (var i in rows) {
                    secondqueryarray.push({
                        name: rows[i].name,
                        email: rows[i].email
                    });
                }
                res.json({
                    secondqueryarray: secondqueryarray
                });
            });
        }
      ]
    )
};
```

Comment: is that `]` out of place? using parallel, wouldn't you want to pass two (or more) functions in that array? otherwise, what's the point of using parallel?

Comment: @KevinB, the `]` is not out of place, but you are correct in pointing out that this does not take advantage of parallelism.

Comment: Please see updated answer...

Comment: @KevinB, the ] is indeed out of place, i'll chance that in a minute

Comment: and now you're missing a callback for .parallel, which again makes it pointless!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might consider the conventional camelCase here (i.e., `secondQueryArray` as a variable name).

`async.parallel` will execute all functions in the array passed as its first argument one after the other rapidly, and once all have returned, execute the second function passed to it.

Therefore:

You currently have your two functions done oddly (one inside the array, one outside and passed as a second argument). Instead of one inside the array, and one outside the array, you should have both of the functions you have in the array. Both of the functions in the array should have their `res.json()` calls replaced with `collection.push()` calls. **Then**, as your second argument to async.parallel, you should have a function (which will execute after all calls in the array have finished) that executes `res.json(collection)`.

```
exports.relations = function (req, res) {

    var collection = { collection:[] };

    async.parallel([
        function () {
            var firstQueryArray= [];
            connection.query(query1, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                for (var i in rows) {
                    firstQueryArray.push({
                        name: rows[i].name,
                        email: rows[i].email
                    });
                }
                collection.collection.push(firstQueryArray);
            });

        },
        function () {
            var secondQueryArray= [];
            connection.query(query2, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

                for (var i in rows) {
                    secondQueryArray.push({
                        name: rows[i].name,
                        email: rows[i].email
                    });
                }
                collection.collection.push(secondQueryArray);
            });
        }],
        function() {
            res.json(collection);
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: I would love to hear an explanation for the downvote(s). This isn't necessarily how I would write this code, but I favor responding with the minimum changes necessary to answer the question, so that the relevant differences are as clear as possible...